# Docker publish not working correctly for golang application

Tags: go, docker

I am trying to run a [golang web server application](https://github.com/maddyonline/gotutorial) (which tries to run a go blog powered by same tools which power [golang blog](http://blog.golang.org/)) via docker. It runs fine without docker but fails to give any response if I use docker. I have no clue why this is happening as for a much simpler [go web application](https://github.com/maddyonline/gowebapp), the same docker based approach works great. See below for output of various commands I used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
docker pull maddyonline/gotutorial
docker run -d --publish 8080:8080 --name gotut maddyonline/gotutorial
```

> 81bc36e385286326a6d9f74322515a7b9748e493275c3426bcc6848a4589a7e7

```
docker ps
```

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
>   81bc36e38528        maddyonline/gotutorial   "go-wrapper run"    20
>   seconds ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   gotut

```
curl localhost:8080
```

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

```
docker exec gotut curl localhost:8080
```

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> ```
>
> And rest of the file

The docker file I am using is very simple.

```
FROM golang:onbuild
EXPOSE 8080
```

I experimented with the same docker file with a much simpler golang application on the same server. And it works.

```
docker pull maddyonline/gowebapp
docker run -d --publish 8080:8080 --name gowebapp maddyonline/gowebapp
curl localhost:8080/icecream
```

> Hi there, I think I love icecream!

Comment: I'd need to see the Go code, but I suspect you've bound to localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two issues with your current code.

The first is that the string `localhost` in your `main.go` needs to be `0.0.0.0`. The problem is that you've told your webserver to only serve requests sent to `localhost`. Because of the network mangling that Docker does, none of the traffic showing up to your webserver look to the webserver as though they were sent to `localhost`. By telling your webserver to listen on `0.0.0.0` you're effectively telling it that it doesn't care where the traffic was originally sent and it will accept it all.

```
var (
    httpFlag   = flag.String("http", "0.0.0.0:8080", "HTTP listen address") // <--- Here it the change. It's roughly line 25 of [main.go](https://github.com/maddyonline/gotutorial/blob/master/main.go#L25)
    originFlag = flag.String("origin", "", "web socket origin for Go Playground (e.g. localhost)")
    baseFlag   = flag.String("base", "", "base path for articles and resources")
)
```

The second issue has to due with your import paths colliding with the predetermined directory structure of the `onbuild` Dockerfile from which you were extending. I saw that you were trying to hardcode the import path, which is not a good idea, but I think it was your only option due to the weirdness of the `go-wrapper` that was being forced onto you by the `onbuild` Dockerfile. Ultimately you should just have the docker build process stick a static Go binary in that container. That will simplify the process of actually starting up the server in the container.

I didn't mess with your paths in your Go code, I figured you could work that out, but I did grab the upstream `onbuild` Dockerfile and customize it to what you need. BTW, if you look at the [documentation](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/golang/) for the `onbuild` Dockerfile it actually says that it's a bad idea to use that Dockerfile. ;) So, I took their advice and here is my port:

```
FROM golang:1.4.2

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/maddyonline/gotutorial
WORKDIR      /go/src/github.com/maddyonline/gotutorial

ADD . /go/src/github.com/maddyonline/gotutorial
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["go-wrapper", "run"]
```

Your other sample server app didn't have the same issues because the import paths weren't specified in the same way they are in this project. Basically, it didn't care where it was living because its dependencies were not being hardcoded to a file path. It is using the normal Go packaging conventions.

Sorry, it probably seems like a lot of change, but I hope it at least helps you move forward on your project. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! This was a very helpful reply. Just doing the first step of your answer (changing localhost to 0.0.0.0) already solved the problem for me.

Comment: A quick follow up question if you don't mind. Even though blog is being served correctly, the blog also starts a web socket connection which fails in handshake because of the origin check made [here](https://github.com/maddyonline/tools/blob/master/playground/socket/socket.go#L93).

Comment: Specifically, the connection origin host and websocket origin don't match: 0.0.0.0:8080, localhost:8080. Any suggestions how to get around this (other than updating the [code in socket.go](https://github.com/maddyonline/tools/blob/master/playground/socket/socket.go#L93)).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. I was thinking you could set an allow-origin CORS header to get around it. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Ooooh. Dang, that is being hard-checked in the Go websockets library you are using. I am not sure there is a way around it without changing that code. I originally thought it was a the browser blocking the request.

Comment: Yeaah I think I will change the socket library code. FYI, will award the bounty as soon as the 5 hour wait time (imposed by stackoverflow) finishes.

Comment: Thanks! My first bounty.

Comment: Thank you so much changing from localhost to 0.0.0.0 saved my day. this answer required more upvote